# Get attribute where subtag has attribute x

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Consider this XML File structure

```
...
<sometag attr="foobar">
    <subtag>
        <subsubtag someattr="foo" />
        <subsubtag someattr="bla" />
        <subsubtag someattr="bar" />
    </subtag>
</sometag>
...
```

currently i have this XPath Query: `/sometag/subtag/subsubtag[@someattr='foo']` which gets me these subsubtags. Is it possible to get the `attr="foobar"` from this query? so i want to have all `attr` from `sometag` where there is a `subsubtag` with `someattr="foo"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the xml file:

```
<root>
<sometag attr="foobar1"> 
  <subtag> 
    <subsubtag someattr="foo"/>  
    <subsubtag someattr="bla"/>  
    <subsubtag someattr="bar"/> 
  </subtag> 
</sometag>
<sometag attr="foobar2"> 
  <subtag> 
    <subsubtag someattr="foo"/>  
    <subsubtag someattr="bla"/>  
    <subsubtag someattr="bar"/> 
  </subtag> 
</sometag>
<sometag attr="foobar3">
    <subtag>
        <subsubtag someattr="f2342oo" />
        <subsubtag someattr="bla" />
        <subsubtag someattr="bar" />
    </subtag>
</sometag>
</root>
```

try:

```
/root/sometag/subtag/subsubtag[@someattr='foo']/../../@attr
```

I made a quick test on [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/test), and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: no, I had first made a mistake and I was selecting the entire `sometag` element , not only it's @attr ; before writing the complete answer I had to do some testing and I didn't want my bad answer to be visible in the meantime.

Comment: weird... because i wanted to accept it and then i got an error message "the answer has been deleted"...

Answer (score 2):

another possibility i just found out:

```
/sometag/subtag/subsubtag[@someattr='foo']/../../@attr
```

you can use `..` to select the parent node. you need to go up in hirachie and select the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
/sometag[subtag/subsubtag[@someattr="foobar"]]/@attr
```

or less strictly:

> //sometag[//subsubtag[@someattr="foobar"]]/@attr

Comment: can you say if this method will be faster then the other? Is there a difference in the XPath Compiler, or will he reduce it to the same AST?

Comment: First method will be faster then second(in most of cases, which depend on particular XPath engine), because in second method some XPath engines will traverse more nodes to find the tag. 
Do you have to use first or second ? It depends. If it's HTML tree, then I would use second, because I don't want to change XPath expression each time HTML layout changes. If it's XML document, then I would stick with first method.